# Call to a member function load() on null Yii2

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

I am new to `Yii2` framework. I am trying to save a form but I am unable to do it. The form look like

[image]

The `javascript` is below

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

     var surveyReferences = new Bloodhound({
              datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('meter_msn'),
              queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
              prefetch: 'survey',
              remote: {
                url: '$url2?q=%QUERY',
                wildcard: '%QUERY'
              }
        });

      $('#the-mter-id').typeahead(null, {
            limit: 50,
            name: 'ref-numbers',
            display: 'meter_msn',
            source: surveyReferences,
            suggestion: function(data) {
                    return '<p><strong>' + data.id + '</strong> – ' + data.meter_msn + '</p>';
        }
    }
    );

      jQuery('#the-mter-id').on('typeahead:selected',function(e,datum) {

          var html = '<div class="selcted-meters"><input type="hidden" name="selected_meters[]" value="'+datum.id+'" />'+datum.meter_msn+'<a onclick="$(this).closest(\'.selcted-meters\').remove()">X</a></div>';
           $('#selected_mters_container').append(html);

           $('#routemeters-mter_id').val(datum.meter_msn);
           $('#routemeters-user_id').val(datum.issued_user);
           $('#the-mter-id').typeahead('val','');
      });


});
```

Below is my `actionCreate` function in my `controller`

```
$model = new RouteMeters();

    if (isset($_REQUEST['selected_meters']))
    {
        $m = RouteMeters::findOne($_REQUEST['selected_meters']);

        foreach($_REQUEST['selected_meters'] as $k=>$v)
        {
           $m = RouteMeters::findOne($v);
           $m ->load(Yii::$app->request->post());

           if ($m->save())
           {

               return $this->redirect(['view','id'=>$model->id]);
           }
           else
           {
               return $this->render('create',[
                   'model' => $model,
               ]);
           }


        }
    }else
    {
        return $this->render('create',[
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

Now when I click the create button I am getting the bellow error

> Call to a member function load() on null

Which points to

> $m ->load(Yii::$app->request->post());

I have also searched for the solution but couldn't able to find it. 
Also I have checked the response of `$m` by doing `var_dump($m);` after `lod()` and I am getting the output.

I am stuck to it an don't know what to do

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Why you first search model by array `$_REQUEST['selected_meters']` (I suppose it's an array) before loop and doing nothing with it and then in `foreach` loop searching models by each element of that `$_REQUEST['selected_meters']` array?

Answer (score 0):

`$m = RouteMeters::findOne($v);` is not finding anything, so the best to check for null before loading like 
`if (isset($m)){$m->load(...)`